# How to show the original character like \n \t in mysql in a select statement

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-real-escape-string

when I run select statement from mysql database, characters like \n \t will be escaped. Is there a way to see these original characters in mysql?

What I want to see is something like "java.lang.Exception: Container released on a lost node\r\n\tat"

Comment: Don't you really mean the opposite? You're apparently getting the original character (a literal tabulator or a carriage return) and you want to replace if with a escape sequence.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I do need to see the original one

Comment: [I cannot reproduce it](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8a7905b781885f0e6c19c2add19c8f03). Are you able to create a fiddle that exhibits the issue?

Comment: Want to do this in a qurey or some programming language?

Comment: @SalmanA  the issue is that when I run a sql query with select and where statement, I always find there is a mismatch. Sometimes it is due to "\r\n"  vs  "\n" and sometimes of encoding. However, for these differences, I could not tell from the output by eyes.

Comment: @SalmanA  I mean when selecting a varchar field with 'like' or '=' operator, I meet this issue

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE column_name REGEXP "\n" 
OR column_name REGEXP "\t";
```